# Windows task copy error The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, windows-server-2012

### Windows task copy error The specified network name is no longer available.
Ma
Maryam

Reported Nov 16, 2022
We have created our Azure Devops pipeline for than a year and half and it was working.
In there we have a step that copied files from Azure Devops Server staging folder to our App and Web Server inetpub.
No problem with App servers but our Windows task Copy to Web server which are in DMZ Devops hangs and we receive following error

E:\Agent_Build_1-1_work\r31\a_x\drop_PublishedWebsites\StagingFolder_DEV\x\bin\ISecurity.dll
The specified network name is no longer available.

This only happens on one file which is Our ISecurity.dll ( It seems that windows server for some reason lock it)

At this point i have to go to ComputerMangment and under OpenFiles find that file which in in inetpub and close it manually and then pipeline is going.

It is strange as on each release we tear the Webserver delete it from IIS and also delete the files, so we are not overwriting.

Here is the image in Devops
[image]
Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Maryam

Comment: You should check that your question is on-topic before posting. This is not a programming question. Ask on [sf]

Comment: To check if the issue is from your local agent environment configuration, have you tried to use az copy tool for this operation off Azure DevOps Server?

Answer (score 0):

I was using remote windows task copy. It works for my app servers but not on my webservers that are on DMZ. It was working for 1.5 and all of a sudden windows locking only on file in Windows open file.
I found a work around and created a PowerShell script to copy to the remote server and this fixed the issue.
Still I do not understand why all of a sudden windows lock out security dll.(It was the first time after 1.5 that we were changing it).

Any ]how for now my issue is resolved!

Thanks,

Maryam

Comment: hi great to hear your issue resolved, to benefit more developers, you could look into this [wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to highlight your answer.